# Magento 2: How to move amazon pay button on the checkout page down so it appears just before the Shipping Methods on the same checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, amazon

[image]
This is the screenshot of the checkout page on my Magento 2 site using Argento luxury Theme. I am trying to move the Amazon Pay button down so the user may not have necessarily thought it is the only payment method offered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have check this problem but I think it is not possible because Amazon Pay is a `'checkout method'`, not a `'payment method'`. So in contrast to a usual payment method, it provides the user the possibility to select an address that is stored within his Amazon account, so the user doesn't need to enter this information manually on the regular checkout page.

But read more helpful this link :-

**https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/amazon-pay-setup.html**

Comment: You are right in saying that it is a checkout method. I ended up finding an alternative approach to my objective.

Comment: so i think no possible move the Amazon pay button

Comment: I had to override the template file of Amazon Pay Module so that I could add an image that I wanted adjacent to Amazon Pay

Comment: I think so, also it won't be nice to have it at the bottom which would let the customer only after filling the information which will defeat the purpose